# New column to divide a 'grouped sum' by a 'grouped count'

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to do something very simple, but I can't.

I want to divide the USD Value by the number of projects (which is a grouped value/a calculated field/a count of all projects by an operator) to get an 'Avg. project value by operator'.

I've tried

```
> Avg. project value by operator = DIVIDE(SUM(df[Value Million U S
> D]),COUNT(df[Project Id]))
```

but I don't get a correct result.

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. Are you trying to create a measure or a new column?

Comment: And is it possible that you once counted all ProjectIDs and once the unique ones?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am not sure, it's my first time using Power BI, but I think I am trying to create a new column. In the original dataset, operator 'a' appears 107 times and the total value (the sum) of all their projects is $180569. Now I would like to see what the average project value is for each operator.

Comment: Could you post some screenshots? It really depends if you're doing a measure, a new column and if your talking about a visual (table) or data (table).